# Some questions about the (projectivized cotangent bundle of the) symmetric square of a genus $3$ curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, algebraic-surfaces

Let $C$ be a smooth, non-hyperelliptic curve of genus $3$ and $X:= \mathrm{Sym}^2{C}$ its symmetric square. Then $X$ is a smooth, minimal surface of general type with $p_g=q=3, \, K^2=6$.

Calling $\Omega_X$ the cotangent bundle of $X$, we see that $\Omega_X$ is globally generated and $h^0(X, \, \Omega_X)=3$; in fact, since $C$ is non-hyperelliptic, the Albanese map of $X$ is an embedding into a principally polarized abelian threefold.

For all $a \in C$, denote by $C_a$ the curve in $X$ given by
$$C_a:=\{ a+x \; | \; x \in C \}.$$ Then $\mathscr{C}:=\{C_a \}$ is an irreducible, $1$-dimensional family of smooth curves on $X$, parametrized by $C$; every $C_a \in \mathscr{C}$ is isomorphic to $C$ and satisfies $(C_a)^2=1$.

> **Question 1.** For some undirect reason, I know that the restriction of $\Omega_X$ to $C_a$ splits and contains a trivial
> summand. What is a direct proof of this fact? Is there any reference?

Consider now the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{P}(\Omega_X) @>{\psi}>> \mathbb{P}H^0(X, \, \Omega_X) \simeq \mathbb{P}^2\\
 @V{\pi}VV\\
X  {}
\end{CD}

where $\pi \colon \mathbb{P}(\Omega_X) \to X$ is the standard projection and $\psi \colon \mathbb{P}(\Omega_X) \to \mathbb{P}^2$ is induced by the complete linear system $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(\Omega_X)}(1)|$.

By the fact mentioned in Question 1, the map $\psi$, when restricted to the ruled surface $\pi^{-1}(C_a)$, contracts a section (corresponding to the trivial summand  of the restriction of $\Omega_X$ to $C_a$) to a point $p_a \in \mathbb{P}^2$. Call $\Delta$ the locus described in $\mathbb{P}^2$ by the points $p_a$, when $C_a$ varies in $\mathscr{C}$.

> **Question 2.** Does $\Delta$ coincide with the canonical image of $C$?

Finally note that, if $p_a \in \Delta$, then $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{C_a = \pi(\psi^{-1}(p_a))}$ $C_a$ is a component of $\pi(\psi^{-1}(p_a))$.

> **Question 3.** Take any point $q \in \mathbb{P}^2$ such that $q \notin \Delta$. What is $\pi(\psi^{-1}(q))$?

Answer (score 5):

Question 1: This has nothing to do with the genus.

$C_a$ is the image of a map $C \to C \times C \to X$ so  $\Omega_X |_{C_a} $ maps to the restriction of $\Omega_{C\times C}$ to $a \times C$, which is $\mathcal O_C \oplus \omega_C$.

This map of vector bundles is an isomorphism away from $a$, so it is an injection of sheaves with cokernel supported at $a$. The cokernel has length $1$ since $C_a$ intersects the branch divisor of $C \times C \to X$, where the ramification has order $2$, transversely. Furthermore, we can check that each factor $\mathcal O_C$ and $\omega_C$ has nontrivial map to the cokernel. A quick way to see this is that sections of $\Omega_X$ come from 1-forms on $C$, with the map to $\omega_C$ given by taking the fiber of the $1$-form at $x$ and the map to $\mathcal O_C$ given by taking the fiber at $a$, so in the $x=a$ case both these $1$-forms are nonzero.

We have an exact sequence $$0 \to \Omega_X|_{C_a} \to \mathcal O_C \oplus \omega_C \to \mathcal O_{\{a\}} \to 0.$$

This gives a natural map $ \Omega_X|_{C_a} \to \mathcal O_C$. To split that map, consider the long exact sequence on global sections

$$0 \to H^0(X, \Omega_X|_{C_a}) \to H^0(C,\mathcal O_C) \oplus H^0(C, \omega_C) \to \kappa $$
where $\kappa$ is the base field. The last arrow can be written concretely as $(s_1, s_2) \to \alpha_1 s_1(a) + \alpha_2 s_2(a)$ where $s_1, s_2$ are sections of $\mathcal O_C$ and $\omega_C$ respectively and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are nonzero by the earlier nontriviality.  Then because $\omega_C$ is globally generated, we can choose a section $s_2$ with $s_2(a) = - \alpha_1/\alpha_2$, and then $(1,s_2)$ is a section   of $\Omega_X|_{C_a}$ that maps to the unit section of $\mathcal O_C$ and thus gives a splitting. Note that the splitting depends on a choice.

Question 2: Yes.

Luckily, our choice doesn't matter for the definition of $\Delta$. Points of the projectivization correspond to one-dimensional quotients of the underlying vector space, so the points corresponding to the $\mathcal O_C$ summand you are looking for are the points corresponding to the $\mathcal O_C$ quotient, which is canonically defined by pulling back a differential on $X$ to $C \times C$ and evaluating in the direction of varying $a$.  So $p_a$ is the point corresponding to the linear form on $H^0(X, \Omega_X) = H^0(C,\omega_C)$ obtained by taking a global $1$-form, restricting to the divisor $[x]+ [a]$, and then evaluating at $a$. This is the same as just evaluating at $a$, which of course is the point corresponding to $a$ under the canonical embedding.

Claim between Question 2 and Question 3: I don't believe this is true. I think $ \pi ( \psi^{-1} ( p_a))$ has another component, consisting of pairs $b,c\in C$ such that $ \omega_C ( -a-b-c)$ has a global section.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will check the details.  By any chance, do you have any clue about Question 3?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Here is the best description I found: Any point of $\mathbb P^2 \setminus \Delta$ defines a map $C \to \mathbb P^1$ of degree $4$ by projecting from that point. From any degree four covering of curves we can make a degree six covering, points of whose fibers, correspond to size two subsets of the fiber of the original covering, and the total space of the associated degree $6$ covering  is $\pi ( \psi^{-1} (q))$.

Comment: I am checking the details, and everything seems ok, so far. May I ask you how you detected the other component of $ \pi ( \psi^{-1} ( p_a))$?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I think of $\mathbb P H^0(X, \Omega_X))$ as the space of nontrivial linear forms on 1-forms, up to scaling, and $\pi^{-1} (b+c)$ as the space of linear forms that depend only on the values of the 1-form at $b$ and $c$, i.e. linear forms vanishing on the unique $1$-form that vanishes on $b$ and $c$. Then $p_a$ is the linear form evaluation at $a$, so $\psi^{-1}(p_a)$ consists of all pairs $b+c$ such that the linear form evaluation at $a$ vanishes on the unique $1$-form vanishing at $b$ and $c$, or in other words such that there exists a $1$-form vanishing at $a,b,c$.

Comment: This can clearly happen even if $a\neq b, a\neq c$.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that the other component should be the image of $C_a$ under the bicanonical involution of $X$ (it is known that the bicanonical map of $X$ has degree $2$ onto its image, and the corresponding involution sends $x+y$ to $K_C-x-y$).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yes, that sound right to me.

Comment: I think that $\psi$ "factors" through the canonical map of $X$; hence the curves in $\pi(\psi^{-1}(q))$, where $q$ varies in $\mathbb{P}^2$, are nothing but the canonical system $|K_X|$ of $X$. The two curves in $\pi(\psi^{-1}(p_a))$ correspond to reducible canonical curves of the form $C_a + (K_C-C_a)$. If this is true, then for every curve $C \in |K_X|$ the restriction of $\Omega_X$ to $C$ must split with a trivial factor. Is there a quick way to check this?

Comment: Note that this agrees with your description of $\pi(\psi^{-1}(q))$, at least for the genus. The $6 : 1$ cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ you described above is branched over the  points corresponding to the $4 \times 3=12$ tangent lines from $q$ to the canonical image $\Delta$ of $C$. Generically, we have a simple tangent point $x$, hence instead of six points in the fibre we have four of them, namely $(x, \, x), (a,\, b) \, (x, \, a), \, (x, \, b)$, with non-trivial ramification only in the last two (I think)...

Comment: ...Then the Hurwitz formula tells us that the genus $g$ of  $\pi(\psi^{-1}(p_a))$ satisfies $$2g-2 = 6(-2)+2 \cdot 12,$$
hence $g=7$, which equals the genus of a smooth canonical divisor of $X$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Yes, this is right. For $x\in X$, $\psi(\pi^{-1}(x))$ is a line in $\mathbb P^2$, which gives a point in the dual $\mathbb P^2$. Then $\pi( \psi^{-1}(q))$ is the pullback of a line in the dual $\mathbb P^2$. So your claim is that the pullback of $\mathcal O(1)$ from the dual $\mathbb P^2$ is the anticanonical class. This follows from the explicit description of the cotangent bundle. More generally, I think the natural map $\operatorname{Sym}^n C \to Gr(n,g)$ pulls back the Plucker line bundle to the canonical bundle of $\operatorname{Sym}^n C$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you see a quick, self-contained argument to show that for every (say, smooth) curve $C$ in the canonical system of $X$, the restriction of $\Omega_X$ to $C$ splits with a trivial factor?